# WP: import custom fields for taxonomy term

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to import some terms for custom taxonomies. Those terms have custom fields(added with ACF). I know I can insert terms with:

```
wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() );
```

I can't add values for the custom fields though.

Is there some way I can add custom fields to this function? Or use CSV somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using wp_insert_term it will return you an array with the Id and the term (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Return_Values)

Then you just have to use add_term_meta (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta)

Example :

```
$term = wp_insert_term('red', 'colour');
add_term_meta($term['term_id'], 'rgba', '#FF0000');
```

Comment: How do I retrieve these return values?

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array"

Comment: use var_dump() with $term.
Does your taxonomy exist ?

Comment: it says this: "A term with the name provided already exists with this parent"

Comment: When I use get_term_meta I can see that information has been added. Though the fields in the form have not been changed